# Magento 2 plugins (interceptor) beforeCancel() making the cancel order bug

Tags: magento2, plugin, before-plugin, cancel-orders

I have created a plugin which intercept the cancel function from the interface **Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface**, the plugin intercept **before** the cancel function is called.

My problem is that when my module is activated, I can't cancel any orders, neither from the page **admin/sales/order/view/order_id/10** or from the list of orders.

For example, when i click the cancel button, the text "You canceled the order." is displayed but in fact the order isn't canceled and has still the status "*pending*".

I have a custom table which reference the **sales_order** table, but the attribute referencing the table has the action on delete cascade

```
->addColumn(
                    'sales_order_id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    10,
                    ['nullable' => false,
                    'unsigned' => true],
                    'Reference to entity_id of table sales_order'
                )
->addForeignKey(
                    $installer->getFkName('my_custom_table', 'sales_order_id', 'sales_order', 'entity_id'),
                    'sales_order_id',
                    $installer->getTable('sales_order'), /* main table name */
                    'entity_id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
                )
```

But even with the action on delete cascade, before canceling an order, I'm deleting the record which is referencing to the order being cancelled.

After cancelling an order, the order is not deleted from the database and has the status cancelled, so I'm getting confused on how can my module make the cancel function bug.

The purpose of my function beforeCancel is only to remove the record with an particular id from the table referencing the sales_order table and add it into an other table having no reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, nothing about the foreign key.

In order to create the plugins I first went to the interface defining the cancel order function which was declared as

```
     /**
     * Cancels a specified order.
     *
     * @param int $id The order ID.
     * @return bool
     */
    public function cancel($id);
```

So I did declare the plugin in my **module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="before_cancel_order_operation"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderManagement"/>
</type>
```

Then in my **Module/Plugin/OrderManagement.php** file I added the function

```
public function beforeCancel(
        OrderManagementInterface $subject,
        int $id
    ) {
       /* Logic code */
      return true;
      }
```

So my thinking was since the cancel function in the **OrderManagementInterface.php** return a boolean (the doc is specifying that the function return a boolean), it should return true if my logic code doesn't encounter a problem.

I was wrong,
returning false will lead me to an error which tells me something like 'you need to provide an id to cancel an order'
returning true will lead me to an error which tells me that I can't cancel order.

I just had to remove the return...

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused about your requirement.

So far my understanding, you want to **remove a record from your table** which related with your **cancelled Order**. If this requirement then you're doing wrong bcoz of Foreign Key means when an order delete from **sales_order** table then a record from `custom_table` will be removed.

In Magento, an order is cancelled  NOT means Delete the order from `sales_order`. It is status changed to Cancel.

So, you want to remove the record from the database table `my_custom_table` when order cancels then you have do below steps:

- Remove Foreign Key  related to `my_custom_table`'s table
  `sales_order_id` column.
- Create an **after** Plugin on `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::cancel` and delete record..

#### Here the Plugin Class

```
<?php


namespace StackExchange\MagentoTest\Plugin\Magento\Sales;


class OrderManagement
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order
     */
    private $orderResource;

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $orderResource
    ){
        $this->orderResource = $orderResource;
    }

    public function cancel(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface $subject,
        $result,
        $id) {

        $where = [
            ' sales_order_id = ? ' => $id
        ];
        try {
            $this->orderResource->getConnection()->delete(
                $this->orderResource->getTable('my_custom_table'),
                $where
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried to do afterCancel, but the problem was that the $id received in the parameters of the afterCancel was always equals to 1. What is the problem with the foreign key here? I don't get it since the record is not being deleted but the only the status is changed?